# I tried installing uvicorn through "pip install "uvicorn[standard]" ", got the following error:

Tags: python, rest, fastapi, web-development-server, uvicorn

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

i went ahead and downloaded [Microsoft C++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)

What should i install? Since there's a bunch of stuff

Answer (score 7):

Because you are using windows, cython based dependencies, Uvloop and Httptools in this case, are not installable. So instead of `pip install uvicorn[standard]`, just go with `pip install uvicorn` and it will work fine.

Comment: ohh, it worked,
thanks